# VBScript Error 52 Bad file name or number

Tags: vbscript, wsh, avaya

I have a VBScript which is used in Avaya CMS to generate a CSV every 3 seconds. This CSV is then read on each change by a node server.

Every now and then it will throw an error (Error 52) and it then requires someone to manually click OK on the prompt and then it continues.

I didn't write the initial script, but I have been trying to fix it so it doesn't throw this error.

As far as I understand, the issue is being caused when the script tries to write to the file when the node server is trying to read the file.

So far I have tried to fix this by making the file read only, then, in the script it makes it writeable, writes to it and makes it read only again.

I thought this had fixed the issue, but I have received Error 52 pop up again and now I am unsure.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get VB/Avaya to ignore the error? I was thinking something like putting `On Error Resume Next` before the line that writes the file?

I know ignoring errors is not good practice, but in this case, if it does ignore it, it just means the file wont be updated on this loop, but 3 seconds later it will loop again so it should be fine.

Script:

```
On Error Resume Next

cvsSrv.Reports.ACD = 1
Set Info = cvsSrv.Reports.Reports("Real-Time\Designer\Skill Status")

If Info Is Nothing Then
Else
  b = cvsSrv.Reports.CreateReport(Info,Rep)
  If b Then
    Rep.RefreshInterval = 3
    Rep.SetProperty "Split/Skill","5"

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    theHTMLLocation = "C:\wamp\www\wallboards\agent_status.csv"

    theSleepFile = "C:\wamp\www\wallboards\sleep.vbs"

    theTemplateLocation = ""
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set gfile = fso.GetFile("C:\wamp\www\wallboards\agent_status.csv")

    Do While Rep.Window.Caption <> ""
      gfile.Attributes = 0

      d = Rep.ExportData("C:\wamp\www\wallboards\agent_status.csv", 44, 0, False, True, True)

      gfile.Attributes = 1

      WshShell.Run "wscript.exe """ & theSleepFile & """", , True
    Loop

    If Not cvsSrv.Interactive Then cvsSrv.ActiveTasks.Remove Rep.TaskID
    Set Rep = Nothing
  End If
End If
Set Info = Nothing
```

P.S - I left out some Parameters at that start of the file which I don't think are relevant, if someone thinks they are I will add them.

[image]

Comment: AFAICS nothing in the code you posted should be raising an [error 52](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231024%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). Please show the exact error message.

Comment: I will post a screenshot of it as soon as it pops again, however it is only happening intermittently so it may be a while before I can post it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I got the error message over the weekend. I have posted a screenshot of it.

Comment: That's an error from your CMS, not from the VBScript. You need to take it up with Avaya's tech support as mentioned in the error message.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I understand that Avaya is throwing the error, but isn't the error still a VB error? I have a few of these reports being generated, but this is the only one that throws this error. If it was an avaya issue, shouldn't I expect to see the same issue across my other reports also?

Comment: Correct, it's a *VB* error, not a *VBScript* error.

Comment: Ah okay. Right so, I guess I will have to get in touch with Avaya. Thanks :)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Hi, so its been a while, but unfortunately I am still having this issue. Unfortunately my company is too cheap to contact Avaya and my boss is convinced this is an I/O issue. I have explained what you advised me but to no avail. I wanted to ask if you know if its possible to export the data to a socket or a pipe instead of a file? Thanks